# How to filter the record based on two columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table with 2 columns and i wanted to filter the records where column1 in (Hierarchy,Single) and column2 in ('Relate', 'NoRelate'). but not return the record when Column1 = Single and Column2 = NoRelate.

```
|Column1  |  |Column2 |
|:--------|  |-------:|
|Hierarchy|  |Relate  |
|Hierarchy|  |Norelate|
|Single   |  |relate  |
|Single   |  |Norelate|
```

Expected Output

```
|Column1  |  |Column2 |
|:--------|  |-------:|
|Hierarchy|  |Relate  |
|Hierarchy|  |NoRelate|
|Single   |  |Relate  |
```

Comment: Just type this condition in `where` clause as you've already done in the question. SQL is very close to natural language in this part. There's no `but` operator obviously, use `and` and brackets (`(` and `)`) to group conditions

Comment: Hi @astentx can you help me writing in a SQL format please.

Comment: I cannot because there's an answer with your requirements directly translated to SQL code by @TimBiegeleisen, which you reject.

Comment: If my answer appears wrong to you, then _edit_ your question and include sample input/output data which shows the logic you want.

Comment: HI @TimBiegeleisen i have updated the expected result.please help me.

Comment: @user13949321 You have `relate` instead of `Relate` in your input table.  Maybe that's why you're not seeing what you expect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the expression you have given is working. Thank you. The issue is i have used other filter as well and so the problem. I really thank you for your help. Please excuse if anything wrong from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just write out your conditions here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Column1 IN ('Hierarchy', 'Single') AND Column2 IN ('Relate', 'NoRelate') AND
      NOT (Column1 = 'Single' AND Column2 = 'NoRelate');
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: There should be null handling in transformed `not` part. And `and not (Column1 = 'Single' and Column2 = 'NoRelate')` is more straigthforward copypaste of the requirement

Comment: @user13949321 If so, then you asked the wrong question.  I have answered what you actually did ask above.

Comment: @user13949321 It definitely makes point. Please, add more details to such straight 
 but arguable statements.

Comment: HI @TimBiegeleisen actually i have applied the similar query hint what you have given.[Hierarchy?] IN ('Hierarchy', 'Single') AND Reference IN ('Relate', 'NoRelate') AND
     Not ([Hierarchy?] = 'Single' and Reference = 'NoRelate'). But it still returning the record with single and norelated. Thats the reason i said its not working in my query.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified conditions:

```
SELECT *
  FROM yourTable
 WHERE Column1 = 'Hierarchy'
    OR (Column1 = 'Single' AND Column2 = 'Relate');
```